# `go list` prints out non-existing Target

Tags: go, golint

As per `golint`'s [README.md](https://github.com/golang/lint):

```
To find out where golint was installed you can run `go list -f {{.Target}} golang.org/x/lint/golint`.
```

When I run the command I get:

```
/Users/Marko/go/bin/golint
```

But there is no such file:

```
ls -alF /Users/Marko/go/bin/
total 6432
drwxr-xr-x  3 Marko  staff       96 Nov 29 12:32 ./
drwxr-xr-x  4 Marko  staff      128 Nov 29 12:05 ../
-rwxr-xr-x  1 Marko  staff  3289296 Nov 29 12:32 hello*
```

How can I find out where is `golint`?

Comment: `which golint`.

Comment: Tried it, fails

Comment: Then you do not have golint installed, so what is the question? (on bash you could try `type golint` too).

Comment: I just figured that out, thanks. I'm wondering why does `go list` show it if it is not installed?

Comment: go list shows information about the package and if that package is installed it would go where it says.

Comment: My example above does differently  It showed the same message before and after installing it.

Comment: Go list shows static information about a package. It doesn't matter whether the package is installed or not.

Answer (score -1):

You need to install it first. Run `go get -u golang.org/x/lint/golint`. I'm not sure why does `go list` still list it as a Target, even if it is not installed.